# Google Search not showing all Images

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, images, internet-connection, google-search

How do I fix an issue with Google Search not showing all images? If I search using [Microsoft Bing](https://bing.com) or [Yahoo!](https://yahoo.com), images are showing but when using [Google Search](https://google.com), 3rd row onwards is faulty.

I have tried removing Windows Updates (thinking it was Windows Update), resetting Chrome settings, and enabling javascript.  I tried different browsers, scanning my system for malware, but nothing seems to fix the issue. I am using Windows 10 and currently, there are no new updates available for Windows.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "I have tried removing Windows Update"? How much free disk space do you have? Did you try clearing/ignoring cache with Shift+F5/Ctrl+F5?

Comment: with all you tried it does not sound as if the problem is due to anything on your PC.

Comment: @Destroy666 I noticed this happened after windows update that's why I tried uninstalling windows update. About cache, yes, I have also cleared cache, cookies and history as well. Still the same issue

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Hi. What specifically is the problem? Should I reinstall google?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Chrome? What about another browser, do they work there?

Comment: Yep. Still the same.